# C# WPF System.Drawing.Image to System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf

I use the library spire.pdf to convert a pdf file into pictures, do it through the code available in the documentation. Generates a PDF file to image because he wants them to print, and PDF file itself can not print (I mean the printer)

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            Spire.Pdf.PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
            pdf.LoadFromFile("sample.pdf");

            BitmapSource source;
            Bitmap bmp;

            for (int i = 1; i < pdf.Pages.Count+1; i++)
            {
                source = pdf.SaveAsImage(i);
                bmp = SourceToBitmap(source);
                bmp.Save(string.Format("result-{0}.png", i), ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }

        private Bitmap SourceToBitmap(BitmapSource source)
        {
            Bitmap bmp;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(source));
                encoder.Save(ms);
                bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
            }
            return bmp;
        }
    }
```

My includes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Spire.Pdf;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.IO;
```

but I get an error from 
`source = pdf.SaveAsImage(i);`

```
Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource'    c:\users\łukasz\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication5\WpfApplication5\MainWindow.xaml.cs    39  26  WpfApplication5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `PdfDocument.SaveAsImage` returns a `System.Drawing.Image`, so you don't need to do any WPF to WinForms bitmap conversion.

This should be sufficient:

```
var source = pdf.SaveAsImage(i);
source.Save(string.Format("result-{0}.png", i), ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! There is another way to print pdf files? I have to convert them as images?